# Inline assembly - cdecl and preparing the stack

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, assembly, 32-bit

I've recently been trying to implement dynamic functions in C++ by using a buffer and RAW hexadecimal equivalents of different assembly operators. To illustrate a simple jump:

```
byte * buffer = new buffer[5];
*buffer = '0xE9'; // Hex for jump
*(uint*)(buffer + 1) = 'address destination';
```

I am not experienced in assembly but I know enough to create *very* simple functions. Right now I'm creating cdecl functions in raw memory. The problem is, I do not know how much I want to push the stack (for memory) with `sub`. Let's take this function as an example:

```
int MyTest(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

long TheTest(int x, int y)
{
    return MyTest(x, 5);
}

08048a20 <_Z6TheTestii>:
_Z6TheTestii():
 8048a20:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048a21:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048a23:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 8048a26:   c7 44 24 04 05 00 00    movl   $0x5,0x4(%esp)
 8048a2d:   00 
 8048a2e:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048a31:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048a34:   e8 c2 ff ff ff          call   80489fb <_Z6MyTestii>
 8048a39:   c9                      leave  
 8048a3a:   c3                      ret
```

As you can see, first is the C++ code and below is the ASM of the 'TheTest' function. One can instantly notice that the stack is pushed for 24 (0x18) bytes (as previously mentioned, I am not experienced using assembly so I might not use the correct terms and/or be completely right). This does not make any sense for me. How come 24 bytes is required when only 2 different integers are used? The variable 'x' is used, which is 4 bytes, and the value '5' which also uses 4 bytes (remember it's cdecl so the calling function takes care of memory regarding the function *arguments*) does not make up for 24....

Now here is an additional example which makes me *really* wonder about the assembly output:

```
int NewTest(int x, char val) { return x + val; }

long TheTest(int x, int y)
{
    return NewTest(x, (char)6);
}

08048a3d <_Z6TheTestiiii>:
_Z6TheTestiiii():
 8048a3d:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048a3e:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048a40:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8048a43:   c7 44 24 04 06 00 00    movl   $0x6,0x4(%esp)
 8048a4a:   00 
 8048a4b:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048a4e:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048a51:   e8 ca ff ff ff          call   8048a20 <_Z7NewTestic>
 8048a56:   c9                      leave  
 8048a57:   c3                      ret
```

The only difference here (except the values)  is the fact that I use a 'char' (1 byte) instead of an integer. If we then look at the assembly code, this pushes the stack pointer for only 8 bytes. That's a difference of *16* bytes from the previous example. As an out-and-out C++ person, have I no clue what's going on. I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me on the subject!

NOTE: The reason why I'm posting here instead of reading an ASM book, is because I need to use assembly for this *one* function. So I don't want to read a whole book for 40 lines of code...

EDIT: I also do not care for platform-dependency, I *only* care about Linux 32bit :)

Comment: Why don't you just use libffi?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's no fun :)

Comment: @Elliott why don't you use a debugger and see what the stack frame looks like inside `TheTest` and see what the extra space is used for?

Comment: @SethCarnegie True enough, but Elliott may be looking for a quick solution rather than *fun*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, I mean no fun for _us_

Comment: @DavidHeffernan About libffi. I've been recommended that by several persons now, but from what I've seen in the libffi code examples, one can only _call_ other functions with it, not _create_ dynamic ones (with malloc/mmap for example). I would be happily proven wrong though, since this have been bothering me for a while...

Comment: @SethCarnegie I'm relative new to Linux so I have no experience using debuggers, and I don't want to start a new project next to my current one (or I'm just a bit lazy...)

Comment: @ElliottDarfink OK, I assumed you were doing codegen to call functions rather than the other way around.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well actually it's both. The problem is, in this case, I would have to utilize the libffi library in pure ASM, and I don't thank that's a nice move :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack frame created in `TheTest` holds both local (automatic) variables and arguments to functions, such as `MyTest` and `NewTest`, called by `TheTest`. The frame is pushed and popped by `TheTest`, so as long as it is big enough to hold the arguments to the functions it calls, the size doesn't matter much.

The compiler output you are seeing is the result of several passes of the compiler. Each pass may perform transformations and optimizations that reduce the frame size required; I suspect at some early state the compiler needed 24 bytes of frame, and never reduced it even though the code was optimized.

The ABI of the compiler on your platform will establish some rules about stack alignment that you must follow, so frame sizes are rounded up to meet these requirements.

These functions use the frame pointer `%ebp%` though this is not a win in code size or performance; this may aid debugging, though.

Comment: What an interesting explanation! Yes I've compiled without any optimization to make the ASM stay simple. But how true is your statement about _so as long as it is big enough to hold the arguments to the functions it calls, the size doesn't matter much_? The thing is, I have a vector which encloses a structure. This structure defines different types (their size and if they are a pointer/reference). Could I just calculate the size of all arguments and then push the stack (and also align it to a power of 2)? For a dirty example: http://pastebin.com/mV4bHkVr

Comment: Yes, but you probably should round up to a multiple of 8: sizeToPush = (sizeToPush + 7) & -8;

Comment: Wow, that was some hefty bit of a code there. I usually understand code snippets, so this was a bit embarrassing, but I can count on that code snippet to align my code to a multiple of 8? Don't want to end up with demolished software :) EDIT: and it does work with unsigned chars I take it?

Comment: Yes, the snippet just rounds up to the nearest multiple of 8. Using -8 this way depends on twos complement arithmetic, which is not guaranteed by the C standard, but is true of all common processors. If you know the size of the value you're adjusting, you can avoid the twos complement issue by using an unsigned number, e.g.: sizeToPush = (sizeToPush + 7) & 0xFFFFFFF8

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your compiler is making a mistake for the first function (probably missing a stack usage optimization). It's also odd that your compiler is using two instructions (with move to a pre-allocated stack slot) rather than a single push instruction.

Are you compiling without optimization?
Could you post your compiler command line?

Comment: Yes I'm compiling without any optimization. Perhaps that was a stupid move? Since I'm a beginner with assembly I thought it would make sense to compile without any optimization so the code would stay simple...

Answer (score 1):

This is to keep the stack aligned to multiple of 32 bytes so that SIMD instructions can be used with variables on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There is some prologue and epilogue code being inserted into these functions. Try writing your assembly in naked functions, i.e.

```
__declspec( naked ) void UsernameIdTramp() // 10 byter, 5 bytes saves + 5 bytes for tramp
{
    __asm 
    {  
        nop; nop; nop; nop; nop;   // 5 bytes copied from target - 
        nop; nop; nop; nop; nop;   // 5 bytes for the jump back.
    }
}
```